# Use parameter/marker in a xslt query in typoscript

Tags: php, xslt, typo3, typoscript

to start with, i never had to do anything with Typo3. So typoscript was a **real** surprise for me.

I have this Script done, all i have to do is to make it a little more variable, so the **@id=** part should be filled with an parameter from the URL.

```
plugin.xml_xpath_detail < plugin.xml_xpath
plugin.xml_xpath_detail.conf.renderObj > 

plugin.xml_xpath_detail.conf {
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id=123456]
  xpath.limit  = 1

  renderObj >
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.wrap = <div style="padding:20px">|</div>
  renderObj {

     20 = TEXT
     20.data = ###COMP_ID###
     20.wrap = <p style="padding:10px; background-color:lime;">|</p>
     20.required = 1
     20.stripHtml = 0
  }
}
```

I know how to get the Parameter, and so i also have the id in an marker if i need it this way

```
COMP_ID.cObject = TEXT
COMP_ID.cObject.value = GP:job
```

I can output the Parameter any time, as same as the Marker. But i have no idea how to modify the xpath.path to identify the Marker/Parameter.
I tried all i could think of

```
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id=GP:job]
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id={GP:job}]
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id={GP::job}]
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id=###COMP_ID###]
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id='###COMP_ID###']
  xpath.path   = /interface/items/item[@id={###COMP_ID###}]
  ...
```

And all i get is an view with the defined placeholders, unreplaced.

Maybe anyone here can point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I have never used xml_xpath but reading the documentation at http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/xml_xpath/1.3.8/view/1/4/ this example should work as it stats *xpath* can be of type *String / typoscript*:

```
plugin.xml_xpath_detail.conf {
  xpath.path = TEXT
  xpath.path.data = GP:job
  xpath.path.data.intval = 1
  xpath.path.wrap = /interface/items/item[@id=|]
  xpath.limit  = 1
}
```

**Edit:** Added the intval as pgampe noted. This is really a must have!

Comment: I have checked the source code of the extension and *xpath.path* is handled as TS object. Are you sure your GP var is called job? Not tx_yourext_pi1[job] or something like that. Are you using the latest version of the extension?

Comment: it actually worked O_O i messed up some other places in the code. So big thx!

Comment: Make sure to add a ``xpath.path.data.intval = 1`` to avoid any ``XSS`` attacks if your ID is numeric. Otherwiese use ``.htmlspecialchars = 1`` or ``.stripHtml = 1``.

Comment: You are right pgampe. We should never abbreviate those things, as it tends to be forgotten to check for injections.

Comment: also thx for this, didnt thought of this in the first place. intval breaks the output btw, dunno why.